# How can I open LibreOffice .dat files?

Tags: libreoffice, configuration

For example, I have a *~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/autocorr/acor_en-US.dat* file. It isn't plain text; opening it as text gives back gibberish.

How can I open it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of running the command `file ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/autocorr/acor_en-US.dat` in a terminal

Comment: What version and flavor are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`acor_en-US.dat` is a ZIP file so any uncompression tool that supports zip; like `gunzip`.

Answer (score 4):

One tool you can use is GNOME Archive Manager (`file-roller`) to either view the files from within the archive or extract the archive.